# npmパッケージをChefでインストールする方法

Tags: node.js, chef, npm

Chefで npm とそのパッケージ `casperjs`を入れたいのですが方法がわからず躓いています。

今まではNodejs本体だけしか必要なかったので `cookbook/nodejs/recipes/default.rb`に

```
package "nodejs"
```

としていただけだったのですが、`npm`で`casperjs`もインストールする必要が出てきたため公開されてるレシピを利用して設定を行おうとしたのですが使い方がわかりませんでした。

https://github.com/redguide/nodejs

こちらを使ってBerkshelfで以前行った`rbenv`のように必要なパッケージのインストールを行いたいのですが、`include_recipe`を使う方法しか書いておらず先に進めていません。

そもそもこの cookbook が Berkshelf で利用可能かさえもわかっていないのですが、
どのような手順で `npm`をインストールし`casperjs`パッケージを入れるか教えて頂けないでしょうか。

参考までに現在行っている`rbenv`の設定を書いておきます。

#### Berksfile

```
cookbook "rbenv", github: 'fnichol/chef-rbenv'
```

#### nodes/my_node.json

```
"rbenv": {
  "rubies": ["2.2.0"],
  "global": "2.2.0",
  "root_path": "/opt/rbenv",
  "gems": {
    "2.2.0": [
              { "name": "activesupport"}
             ]
  }
},
    "run_list": [
        "rbenv::system"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

上記の質問をした時は疲れていたせいか、どうすればよいか思いつかなかったのですが `rbenv`の場合とほぼ同じ方法でインストール出来ました。

`node/foobar.json`に

```
"nodejs": {
    "npm_packages":[
        {
            "name": "casperjs"
        }
    ]
},
```

という記述と `Berksfile`に

```
cookbook "nodejs", github: 'redguide/nodejs'
```

を追記して実行すると正常にcasperjsが使えるようになりました。